# laravel route redirect issue (laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, routes

I am using a route with any type and then in this method I am treting on the base of a type of request.

**route**

```
Route::any('/setting/custom-header/{id?}', 'SettingController@customHeader');
```

From the controller before checking the type I check it like this

`if ($id == Auth::user()->id || Auth::user()->is_admin){}`

As  where the request is **get** it gives a view and my url is this **http://app-full.dev/setting/custom-header/1**

Here **1** is the id of the user through which I am logged in. I am returning  the view as following:

```
return view('setting/custom-header')->with(compact('custom_headers','id'));
```

It's fine for me.

When request is post it comes in method. After creating data i want return back as above url mean same on **http://app-full.dev/setting/custom-header/1**
mean id at the end through which user logged in here i am using redirect as

```
return redirect('setting/custom-header/id');
```

here /id is actually the id of user .. which I don't know how can I give the id here so that url can come in the proper way instead of keyword id at the end.
Thanks if anyone can help to resolve this issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will retreive the user ID and put it in the URL.

```
return redirect('setting/custom-header/' . Auth::id());
```

To pass it to a view:

```
return view('setting/custom-header')->with(['userid' => Auth::id()]);
```

and then use it:

```
window.location.href = "/setting/custom-header/{{ $userid }}";
```

Comment: thanks its working in above cases i am aslo using in my index in script how can i do for it?
`window.location.href = "/setting/custom-header/id"; `

Comment: You can pass the user ID with your view and print it in the HTML/javascript.
You can read more about it at https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/views#passing-data-to-views. To print the variable you have to use `window.location.href = "/setting/custom-header/{{ $id }}"; `

Comment: i am passing id here as `return view('setting/custom-header')->with(compact('custom_headers','id')); ` don't know how to concatenate there so please

Comment: it says undefined userid

Comment: Please read https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/views#creating-views on how to pass and use a variable in a view or post your blade code.

Answer (score 0):

Make Your Route As Follows

```
Route::post('/setting/custom-header/{id?}',['as'=>'giveSomeName','uses'=>'SettingController@customHeader']);
```

And While Redirect use this name,

```
return redirect()->route('giveSomeName',[$id]);
```

Hope This Works For you